# Get all tags of xml string

Tags: javascript, html, xml

```
<listing>
<address>1440 Church Street NW #307</address>
<id>1884</id>
<mlsid>DC123456</mlsid>
<status>Sold</status>
<type>Condominium</type>
<offer>For Sale</offer>
<price>925000</price>
<beds>2</beds>
<baths>2</baths>
<parking>Off-Street</parking>
<description>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, unum accusamus laboramus id sea, vix te consul cetero. Vis in amet appetere, mel an appetere scripserit sadipscing, everti dignissim delicatissimi ius ex. Has dictas suscipit in. Feugiat vocibus referrentur no mel, in scripserit sadipscing per, at usu facilisi interesset. Ius ut sapientem neglegentur, no enim essent aliquip cum, ad labitur senserit maiestatis est. Epicurei torquatos vim et, saepe pertinax at pri. Est et sale molestiae scriptorem, per ea cibo scriptorem.
</description>
<ibrochure></ibrochure>
<hoodtour>
</hoodtour>
</listing>
```

What I tried

```
getAlltags(string xml){
  var everytag = xml.split('<');
  everytag.forEach(function(tagstring){
     var name = tagstring.split('>')[0];
     console.log(name);
   })
}
```

It is getting the lists of tags but I think it's not good way.
Is there any oneline code to search all tags?
Ther result I want from above xml is `<listing>, <address>, <id>, <mlsid> ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be a lot easier if you parsed the XML string into an actual XML document, and then just use traversal methods and an array, like so

```js
var xmlString = "<listing><address>1440 Church Street NW 307</address><id>1884</id><mlsid>DC123456</mlsid><status>Sold</status><type>Condominium</type><offer>For Sale</offer><price>925000</price><beds>2</beds><baths>2</baths><parking>Off-Street</parking><description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, unum accusamus laboramus id sea, vix te consul cetero. Vis in amet appetere, mel an appetere scripserit sadipscing, everti dignissim delicatissimi ius ex. Has dictas suscipit in. Feugiat vocibus referrentur no mel, in scripserit sadipscing per, at usu facilisi interesset. Ius ut sapientem neglegentur, no enim essent aliquip cum, ad labitur senserit maiestatis est. Epicurei torquatos vim et, saepe pertinax at pri. Est et sale molestiae scriptorem, per ea cibo scriptorem.</description><ibrochure></ibrochure><hoodtour>https%3A%2F%2Fplayer.vimeo.com%2Fvideo%2F97603062%3Ftitle%3D0%26byline%3D0%26portrait%3D0</hoodtour></listing>";

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc    = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "application/xml");
var tags   = [];

doc.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(el => {
    if ( tags.indexOf(el.tagName) === -1 ) tags.push(el.tagName);
});

console.log(tags);
```

If even more ES2015 is okay, one could use a Set for unique values

```js
var xml = "<listing><address>1440 Church Street NW 307</address><id>1884</id><mlsid>DC123456</mlsid><status>Sold</status><type>Condominium</type><offer>For Sale</offer><price>925000</price><beds>2</beds><baths>2</baths><parking>Off-Street</parking><description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, unum accusamus laboramus id sea, vix te consul cetero. Vis in amet appetere, mel an appetere scripserit sadipscing, everti dignissim delicatissimi ius ex. Has dictas suscipit in. Feugiat vocibus referrentur no mel, in scripserit sadipscing per, at usu facilisi interesset. Ius ut sapientem neglegentur, no enim essent aliquip cum, ad labitur senserit maiestatis est. Epicurei torquatos vim et, saepe pertinax at pri. Est et sale molestiae scriptorem, per ea cibo scriptorem.</description><ibrochure></ibrochure><hoodtour>https%3A%2F%2Fplayer.vimeo.com%2Fvideo%2F97603062%3Ftitle%3D0%26byline%3D0%26portrait%3D0</hoodtour></listing>";

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc    = parser.parseFromString(xml, "application/xml");
var tags  =  new Set([].map.call(doc.querySelectorAll('*'), z => z.tagName));

console.log(Array.from(tags));
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it will be the easiest way.